# Count Number of Known USB Hardware Ids

Tags: batch-file, usb

Is there a way to run a batch-file counting the number of connected USB devices from a list of known Hardware Ids? A sample hardware Ids: USB\VID_3923&PID_718A. By getting the sum from a list I can insure all measuring devices are connected to my Windows 10 system.

Comment: You can use something like `%__APPDIR__%wbem\WMIC.exe path win32_pnpentity where "Present='True' AND PNPClass='USB'" get HardwareID` to get a list of USB Hardware IDs on your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wmic path win32_pnpentity where "Present='True' AND PNPClass='USB'" get HardwareID | findstr /L "USB\VID_3923&PID_718A USB\VID_12345&PID_987B" |find /c /v ""
```

gets you the number of connected devices from your list (I used just two search-strings; expandable until you hit `findstr`'s search-string length restriction)

Put a `for` loop around to capture the output into a variable:

```
for /f %%a in ('wmic path win32_pnpentity where "Present='True' AND PNPClass='USB'" get HardwareID ^| findstr /L "USB\VID_3923&PID_718A USB\VID_12345&PID_987B" ^|find /c /v ""') do set number=%%a
echo %number% devices from your list connected.
```

Answer (score -1):

You can run this in PowerShell to get a nice list of the USB devices:

```
Get-PnpDevice -PresentOnly | Where-Object { $_. InstanceId -match '^USB\\VID_....&PID_....\\' }
```

If that list looks acceptable to you, you can get the count of USB devices using `( ... ).Count`, like this:

```
(Get-PnpDevice -PresentOnly | Where-Object { $_. InstanceId -match '^USB\\VID_....&PID_....\\' }).Count
```

I'm not exactly sure how to do this from a Batch file but I'm sure you can find info about how to run PowerShell scripts from a Batch file if you do a little bit of searching on this site.